# I need a formula that looks for the first two numbers in a cell and add 0 in front of it

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

***hey***,
Im looking for a formula that looks for the first two numbers in a cell, and if it starts with 13 or 14 and its length is 9 digits, it adds 0 in front of the number. i hope its possible.
for example: i have a big amount of barcodes with different amount of digits, some are 12 digits, some are 6 digits and they may start with any number other than 13 or 14. i need to add "0" to these specific barcodes that start with 13 or 14 and have 9 digits.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please add some examples of your data.

Comment: We are not a formula writing service. What have you tried?

Comment: i tired to select the cells i need to add 0 to, and then format the cells. i cant find a formula that helps me with what i need.

Comment: Show us what you have tried already along with why what went wrong is perplexing to you (and also obstructing doing the natural next step for mitigating that perplexing outcome).

Comment: Hm. I think my edit was in keeping with the original question and the person's comment above, but ok. If this is important to you as a gatekeeper of the community, then so be it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking for the first 2 characters of a string? Use [LEFT](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/left-leftb-functions-9203d2d2-7960-479b-84c6-1ea52b99640c)

```
LEFT(string,2)
```

Looking for the length of a string? Use [LEN](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/len-lenb-functions-29236f94-cedc-429d-affd-b5e33d2c67cb)

```
LEN(string)
```

Want to check if something is true or not? Use [IF](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2)

```
IF(thing=other_thing,TRUE,FALSE)
```

Want to check if more than one thing is true? Use [AND](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/and-function-5f19b2e8-e1df-4408-897a-ce285a19e9d9). If both thing1=thing2 AND thing3=thing4, then the following is TRUE:

```
AND(thing1=thing2,thing3=thing4)
```

Want to check if one thing or another is true? Use [OR](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/or-function-7d17ad14-8700-4281-b308-00b131e22af0). If either thing1=thing2 OR thing3=thing4 then the following is TRUE:

```
OR(thing1=thing2,thing3=thing4)
```

So,

```
=IF(AND(OR(LEFT(A1,2)="13",LEFT(A1,2)="14"),LEN(A1)=9),"0"&A1,A1)
```

This works if your barcodes are alphanumeric. If your barcode is entirely numeric, then concatenating a zero at the beginning will not necessarily work and you will have to change the cell format.

Comment: I respectfully disagree that it encourages anything except to expect help in a community that is for providing help. If it were an established user, I would not post an answer. For brand new users who have commented what they tried, which admittedly should go in the main post, then I think being welcoming is more important than dismissive.